# How to check if an array has an empty value at an unspecified index in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

How can I check if any of the arrays contains empty fields (they are both dynamic arrays so the empty value can be in any index in both of them)?

```
Array1 ( [0] => dfsg [1] => dfasg [2] => d5g [3] => )
Array2 ( [0] => d54fgv [1] => [2] => df4g4 [3] => d645 )
```

It would be good to know at which index as well, otherwise, just to know if there is any empty fields.

Comment: Use `array_search()` to search for an empty string.

Comment: @Barmar that's to be used for finding at a specific index. What if I dont know where the empty value is?

Comment: What do you mean? `array_search` returns the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. One that springs to mind is checking if the count of a filtered version is lesser than the original array. You can even customize this to specify which sort of filter-values you are looking for by supplying a closure to `array_filter()`.

```php
if (count(array_filter($a1)) < count($a1)) {
    echo '$a1 has at least one empty value';
}
```

From the manual of `array_filter()`,

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see [converting to boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/dkGPr.
- Documentation for [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array-filter)

If you need to know which index(es) is empty, you can check the difference of the filtered array with the original array through `array_diff()`. You can then use `array_keys()` on the filtered array to obtain all the indexes.

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/oN8QR
- Documentation for [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/array-diff)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this `if (count(array_filter($a1)) < count($a1))` is not only checking but also filtering right? I dont want to make any changes or filtering in the arrays, I just want to check and notify the user.

Comment: `array_filter()` is not by reference, it just *returns* the filtered array, so it will not change the array you pass through (unless you assign it back, i.e `$a = array_filter($a);`).